# How to fix Image Picker issue in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Using `image_picker: ^0.8.3+2` I'm getting following error.

> The following LateError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state:
> _State#f8278): LateInitializationError: Field '_image@17179966' has not been initialized.

Please have a look in my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<HomePage> {
  late File _image;

  Future cameraImage() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      if (image != null) {
        _image = File(image.path);
      } else {
        print("No Image selected");
      }
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 500,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
                child: _image == null
                    ? Text("No imaged selected!!")
                    : Image.file(_image)),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: cameraImage,
                child: Icon(Icons.camera),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                child: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using the `late` keyword you're telling the compiler this variable will be assigned before it is used. and since you are not doing that, this error is thrown.

I see that you want to work with a nullable version to implement this async widget. you can do that by changing the the `_image` variable to:

```dart
File? _image;
```

another option would be working with a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)